# Proof that electric field inside a dielectric filled between two equipotential surfaces is reduced by a factor $k$ (dielectric constant)

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

Suppose i have an electric field in space (not necessarily uniform), my book says that when a uniform dielectric is filled between any two equipotential surfaces of this external field, the net field in this dielectric is reduced by
$k$ (the dielectric constant), please give me a rigorous mathematical proof for it!

Comment: This is the definition of the dielectric constant, can you elaborate more on what aspect of it you have problems with?

Comment: My textbook gives a proof for : electric field is reduced by K when a uniform dielectric fills entire space . But doesn't give a proof for the above question.

Answer (score 0):

The dielectric material that filled between the two conduction plates induces an electric dipole by the external electric filed, $\vec E$. The electric dipole has an induced polarization $\vec P$, which has residual surface charge in the ends of dieletric material (bound charge). The surface induced charge canceled part of the conduction charge (free charge). The resultant electric field inside the dielectric material are reduced by a factor $k$, the dielectric constant.

[image]

Comment: no offence but this is an answer not even a middle schooler would accept